# Import data into LibreOffice Calc with embedded newlines

Tags: import, libreoffice-calc

Title says it all. I can export to csv or tab delimited or json. But no matter what format I use the data with embedded newlines is messed up:

```
"fieldId","field1","field
2 has newline","field3"
```

I've tried converting the newlines to "\n" but that just imports "field\n2 has newline" into field 2.

Is there a way to do this short of writing code?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. You can just leave the newlines in place if you surround the field with quote marks. The real trick is if there are quote marks in the data you escape them by doubling them. So if your data has "field3" with the quotes part of it data, you get:

```
"field1","field
2 has newline","""field3"""
```